# PDO prepared statement create

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my project to create a new user, using PHP & PDO prepared statements. I can retrieve the table of users, perfectly fine, however, I just cannot get the data that is in the form, sent to the database. Any advice or tips as to what I am doing wrong, would be great, thanks, in advance. Here's my script:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
require_once('connect.php');

try {

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO admin SET username=:username, fName=:fName, lName=:lName, email=:email, userLevel=:userLevel");

    $username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
    $fName = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['fName']));
    $lName = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['lName']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $userLevel = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['userLevel']));

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lName', $lName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userLevel', $userLevel);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Fail</h1>";
    }
}

catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    die('Error: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
}
?> 

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"method="post">
  <table id="createUser">
      <tr>
          <td>
              Username
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="username">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
             First Name
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="fName">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              Last Name
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="lName">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              email
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="email" name="email">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              Access Level
          </td>
          <td>
              <select name="userLevel">
                  <option selected disabled hidden>Please Select</option>
                  <option value="0">Full Control</option>
                  <option value="1">Managed Control</option>
                  <option value="2">Own Page Control</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <td>
          <input type="submit" value="Add User"/>
          <a href="admin.php">Test Link</a>
      </td>
  </table>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this code? You shouldnt store the data with `htmlspecialchars`, use that on outputting.

Comment: I think `SET`goes with `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I'm not sure if PDO supports that SQL syntax. That is not the syntax for an SQL INSERT but for an UPDATE

Comment: @frz3993 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @AndyC https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: As chris85 already mentioned, do not escape the input with `htmlspecialchars()` nor with `strip_tags()`. Escaping should be done as late as possible, in this case only use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting to an HTML page. This is the difference to validation, which should be done as soon as possible.

Comment: @chris85:  Dunno, I just learned somethin ;-)

Comment: I commented the special chars out & still no success. I'm not receiving a success or error, I have no warnings or errors.

Comment: So when you execute the page you receive `Fail`?

Comment: Could you place the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the begin of your php file?

Comment: No, I don't receive anything, it just refreshes the page, as per the form action. I also placed the error report at the beginning of the file and the results were the same. My connection is fine, as my other script can retrieve the records, I can add records from within my IDE, I just cannot get them to send to the database, from my form. I'm obviously doing something wrong and I've been trying to figure it out for hours, but I have hit a wall and cannot think what could be wrong.

Comment: It looks like the `if($_POST)` does return false then or the page is not called at all. Check your form `action` attribute, make it absolut if necessary, and make sure the attribute `method="post"` is defined. Maybe you could show the source of the form, including the form and the submit button.

Comment: Add the form code to the question.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question, with the form code.

Comment: Dump question, but could it be, that the user was successfully created, but the page shows up anyway, because there is nothing to prevent loading the HTML content? In this case just add an exit after the echo `echo "<h1>Success</h1>"; exit();`.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your suggestion, I'm still getting the same behaviour. I also just put an additional else, at the end, to echo 'error' and the error is printed, on the screen. so it would appear that the 'Post' is never initialising. I've set up 2 different redirects, 1 for success and one for fail, obviously after submit, I'm landing on my chosen 'Fail' page.

Comment: Just to eliminate problems, could you place a space before `method="post"`? And could you check in the browser, whether the page was really sent by POST (you can press F12 to open the developer tools)?

Comment: I've swapped things around a little, I'm now getting my errors on screen. It would appear that my column names are the problem, but I don't see how. I've taken the special chars out, it is not posting, for some reason. This is my first time using PDO, could I have missed something, set up wise>? I uncommented 1 line in the php.ini file. Could it be that there is something in PHPStorm, I haven't configured?

Comment: I would go for the standard notation: `"INSERT INTO admin (username, fName, lName, email, userLevel) VALUES (:username, :fName, :lName, :email, :userLevel)"` maybe the other syntax is not entirely supported with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would update this, as I have finally managed to get it working. It turns out my code was correct and PHP Storm does not accept £_POST, for some bizarre reason, due to an update on 10.1. There's a ticket open and many others have had this problem.

I was actually using PHP Storm's built in server, as opposed to Apache, which is why it wouldn't work. I just downloaded Brackets, ran the file to localhost and hey presto, create finally worked.

So, I know my SQL and PDO weren't to blame and once I configure Apache to work with PHP Storm, everything will be fine. Thanks for all of your advice and help.